# Can I specify IP address in Domains for recaptcha-v2

Tags: recaptcha

I have registered a domain but I have not yet assigned an IP address to it as my application is still not ready.

However, the application is on a GCP production environment and I have external IP of the application.

To test the application, can I specify IP address in the domain settings of recaptcha-v2?

Answer (score 0):

it seems I can specify the IP directly in the settings area.